# Java WS Client implementation for dynamic WSDL

Tags: java, webservice-client

I am looking for a way to implement a Java Web Service Client from a WSDL that changes every 3 months once, without re-generating the client side jars.

Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Comment: A change in your WSDL may require an update of the corresponding Java classes.  What is the limitation on regenerating the client side JARs (as annoying as that may be)?

Comment: You'll probably need to recompile WSDL to java classes, so to skip regenerating JARs you'd need to compile WSDL to .java and then .java to .class in the runtime. Are you bound to plain Java, or can you use some tool for runtime code generation?

Comment: Tim : The problem i see here is, every time a change is WSDL is costing me application (web-application) re-deployment, which is indeed so much of pain.

Comment: Filip : I can use some tool. Do you got something to suggest on top of your head?

Comment: @Vivek   The changes of WSDL shouldn't be causing you to change your code. WSDL are allowed to change as long as the contract between server and client doesn't change. For example, the Server can start exposing new methods to clients, but keep old method still the same.

Comment: So..  even though the actual WSDL can be "dynamically" generated every time by the server,  the basic WebService entites like: Operation, Parameter Types, Return Type, and Error Codes, should never change unless the Client is agreeing to change code on the client side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the web service is simple, you may use a "DOM" oriented approach, where you programmatically create/modify the XML document you send in your request, and similarly extract the values from the XML returned in the response.

It's not as bad as it sounds. The APIs are fairly high-level. For instance when calling:

```
    SOAPConnectionFactory soapConnectionFactory = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
    this.soapConnection = soapConnectionFactory.createConnection();

    MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
    SOAPMessage soapMessage = messageFactory.createMessage();
    SOAPPart soapPart = soapMessage.getSOAPPart();

    // SOAP Envelope
    SOAPEnvelope envelope = soapPart.getEnvelope();
    envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("ser", "http://server.splat/");

    // SOAP Body
    SOAPBody soapBody = envelope.getBody();

    SOAPElement soapBodyElem = soapBody.addChildElement(operation, "ser");
    int n = 0;
    for (Object argN : args) {

        SOAPElement soapBodyElemN = soapBodyElem.addChildElement("arg" + n++);
        soapBodyElemN.addTextNode(argN.toString());
    }

    MimeHeaders headers = soapMessage.getMimeHeaders();
    headers.addHeader("SOAPAction", "\"\"");

    soapMessage.saveChanges();

    /* Print the request message */
    debug(operation + " Request SOAP Message:\n" + traceSOAPMessage(soapMessage));

    SOAPMessage soapResponse = this.soapConnection.call(
        soapMessage, this.url
    );
```

Then you've just got to extract the values from `soapResponse`:

```
    Iterator it = soapResponse.getSOAPBody().getChildElements(
        envelope.createName(operation + "Response", null, "http://server.splat/")
    );

    soapBodyElem = (SOAPElement) it.next();
    it = soapBodyElem.getChildElements(
        envelope.createName("return")
    );

    while (it.hasNext()) {

        String value = ((SOAPElement) it.next()).getTextContent();
        System.out.println(value);
    }
```

This style of web service invocation will withstand any trivial changes to the WSDL. Also, it is more compact since you don't have the whole plethora of auto-generated class files to manage.

In my opinion this is a more "honest" approach because you're not "pretending" to be invoking a local method RPC-style.

Of course if the structure of your XML objects flowing back and forth changes in any significant way this won't work, but then again if you understand the ways in which you expect it to change you could develop your application logic in such a way as to anticipate this, or even make it configurable so that the changes can happen without having to redeploy.

Comment: Thanks Robert. I can give it a try and see how it goes. BTW, I have tried to implement Apache's cxf 3.2, which is dynamic jax-ws. Will that help resole my issue?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with CXF but I would say that "as a general principle" if the problem is quite simple you're better off trying to write the code yourself. Better to be debugging your own code than somebody elses if something goes wrong ...